# How to access all data from api if there is a count in that api url

Tags: javascript, api, react-native

I want to get all data from api call but in that api there is a count like limitation 25 so i get only 25 datas from that api response.How can i get all data from that api

`{
    "hasMore": true,
    "totalResults": 129,
    "links": 
[{"href": "https://ecgg-test.fa.us2.oraclecloud.com:443/bpm/api/4.0/"}],
    "count": 25,
    "items": [
        {"number": 247573},
        {"number": 247576},
        {"number": 247578},
        {"number": 247583},
        {"number": 247584},
        {"number": 247586},
        {"number": 247590},
        {"number": 247601},
        {"number": 247602},
        {"number": 247605},
        {"number": 247606},
        {"number": 247607},
        {"number": 247608},
        {"number": 247610},
        {"number": 247620},
        {"number": 247621},
        {"number": 247622},
        {"number": 247623},
        {"number": 247625},
        {"number": 247627},
        {"number": 247628},
        {"number": 247629},
        {"number": 255660},
        {"number": 260042},
        {"number": 260105}
    ]
}`
in the above code total results was 129 but i will get 25 data only because they set count 25 this api from oracle cloud so i can't change count from backend side

there is any solution to get all data from that api?
link for oracle cloud for ref
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/global-human-resources/19a/farws/Retrieving_List_of_Tasks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "limit" and "offset" param as mentioned in their documentation, you can set limit to between 1 and 100, and then you can use "offset" param like 25 to get next 25 records.

Documentation link:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/19c/farca/op-bpm-api-4.0-tasks-get.html

Comment: got it..passing the limit in api url params to get all data

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution with a help of Azhar Rasheed

```
axios.get(/bpm/api/4.0/tasks?limit=100).then((response) => {

console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```

pass the value in api uri header to set limit for the response